# Ambiguous redirect when running command via ssh

Tags: ssh, io-redirection, tcsh

I'm trying to start a program in the background on a remote server via ssh, but this program must be run from the directory it is contained within.

I tried doing the following

```
ssh -q user@server 'cd directory && command > /dev/null 2>&1 &'
```

But this results in the error

```
Ambiguous output redirect.
```

I am redirecting the output to `/dev/null` because otherwise the ssh call would not finish.

I have tried wrapping the command in `{}` and `()`, as well as with and without quotes but get the same error.

How can I work around this issue?

Comment: You've tagged this `bash` - are you sure `user`'s remote shell is not a different shell - perhaps `csh`?

Comment: @steeldriver I'm running the ssh command from bash, but I believe the remote command will be run in csh.

Comment: @steeldriver actually **t**csh, not csh ;-) To the OP: any commands given to ssh will be run with the login shell of the user on the remote machine, whatever that is. Just try `ssh -q user@server 'echo $version'`

Comment: @mosvy running `echo \$version` (had to escape the $) reports `tcsh 6.17.00`

Comment: In csh and tcsh you could redirect both stdout and stderr with `command >& /dev/null` (which, though deprecated also works in `bash`, but not in another bourne shells).

Comment: @mosvy Thanks, that works - feel free to post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned [in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531093/ambiguous-redirect-when-running-command-via-ssh#comment982939_531093), the remote user's login shell is `csh` or `tcsh`.  These shells have very different syntax to the various POSIX shells, and in particular, the syntax for redirections is different.

To redirect both standard output and standard error to `/dev/null` with these shells, use `>& /dev/null`:

```
ssh -q user@server 'cd directory && command >& /dev/null &'
```

Alternatively, explicitly invoke a POSIX shell to run the command:

```
ssh -q user@server 'sh -c "cd directory && command >/dev/null 2>&1" &'
```